# What is the "Android" way to return a lot of data from an activity

Tags: android

I've got a library which exposes an `Activity` meant to be called with `startActivityForResult()`, but the result is going to be thousands of rows of data.  Far more than I'm comfortable returning in the activity's response.  What's the appropriate way to expose this data?

This `Activity` may also be used from other applications that I don't know/trust, so I can't rely on them for any cleanup operations.

Answer (score 1):

Consider placing your data into a ContentProvider before returning. And then in your response pass back a URI that identifies where the data is in the ContentProvider.

The caller can then remove the data from the ContentProvider when they are finished using it (if appropriate)

Comment: Is there a mechanism for indicating that the data isn't needed anymore ?  I don't want to start polluting storage with a ton of data that isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: The ContentProvider exposes a REST like interface, that your client can query against or perform deletes on.  
So you could return a URI from your library that the client can query against to get a Cursor. And then when the client is finished iterating over the data, the client can send the ContentProvider a delete operation to clean the data up

Answer (score 0):

If the activity does not have a UI then use a ContentResolver not an Activity. Or you could return a Cursor over the data. Where are the thousands of rows coming from? If from a DB query in SQL lite then I would say a Cursor is best.

Comment: There is a UI to help select the data.  Can a Cursor be passed back? Across applications?

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in an SQLite database. You should never store "thousands of rows of data" in memory... always store persistent data on the disk.

Comment: Right. But that's not what I'm asking. I need a way to present that data to the calling application, and then clean it up once that application has consumed it.  I don't like the idea of trusting the caller to handle the data correctly and then clean it up when they're done.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not sure how.  I've got Activity A that the user uses to select a bunch of data.  Let's say it's a search form that's backed by a web site.  Once the user does that search I want to return all of their search results to Activity B that started Activity A. Activity B may belong to a different app than A, and may be written by a developer I don't trust to properly clean up resources.  I'm looking for the correct way to expose this data to Activity B without leaking anything. Someone mentioned using a ContentProvider; that seems pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure how cleanup would work.

Comment: @Hounshell So you are implementing an `Activity` that will be invoked by other third-party apps (i.e. by an Intent `ACTION`)? And you are trying to figure out the best way to expose data to the client?

Comment: @Hounshell If that is the case, I don't think it is your job to clean up after the client. Doing so would limit what they are allowed to do with that data... so it should be their job to make sure leaks don't occur.

Comment: @Hounshell You could also just implement a public `ContentProvider` that directly exposes your data to other applications. This way, the clients could simply query the `ContentResolver`. The `Uri` argument in the `getContentResolver().query(...)` method will (securely) forward the query to your `ContentProvider`, which will return the `Cursor` with the requested data. This might give the client more freedom in how they query data (since it wouldn no longer be required to go through your `Activity` for a result... they can just query the `ContentProvider` directly instead).